# Can we decide whether $\sigma(n)-2n=k$ is solvable?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

An integer $\ k\ $ is given.

> Can we decide whether $\ \sigma(n)-2n=k\ $ has a solution and if yes, can we find one solution efficiently ?

The following even numbers were not "covered" by the range $\ [1,10^9]\ $ (That means that for those even $\ k\ $ with $\ |k|\le 1\ 000\ $ upto $\ n=10^9\ $ there is no solution.

```
[-482, 358, 442, 526, 550, 598, 694, 718, 778, 898, 902]
```

Of course, for odd $\ k\ $, the situation is much worse because for $\ n\ge 2\ $ , $\ \sigma(n)-2n\ $ is odd if and only if $\ n=m^2\ $ or $\ n=2m^2\ $ for some positive integer $\ m\ $.

Update : I found a sufficient condition for the existence of a solution :

Suppose , $\ s\ge 1\ $ is an integer such that $$m:=2^s-k-1$$ is an odd prime. With $\ n:=2^{s-1}\cdot m\ $ we have $$\sigma(n)=(2^s-1)(m+1)=2^s\cdot m+2^s-m-1=2n+k$$

Comment: $$n=550007996416$$ gives $\ -482$

Comment: $$549567594496$$ gives $\ 358$

Comment: $2n-\sigma(n)$ is tabulated, with references and links, at http://oeis.org/A033879

Comment: @Peter, I think that your biconditional in the fifth paragraph should be
$$\ldots \sigma(n) - 2n \text{ is odd if and only if } n = m^2 \text{ or } n = 2m^2 \text{ for some positive integer } m.$$

This is so because $2n$ is always even, and $\sigma(n)$ is odd if and only if $n = m^2$ or $n = 2m^2$ for some positive integer $m$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Of course, this is a typo. Thank you for clarifying.